# Context free grammar for $L = \{u\#v \mid u,v \in \{a,b\}^* , \vert u \vert_a \neq \vert v \vert_a \text{ or } \vert u \vert_b \neq \vert v \vert_b\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I try to find a context free grammar for the language  $L = \{u\#v \mid u,v \in \{a,b\}^* , \vert u \vert_a \neq \vert v \vert_a \text{ or }  \vert u \vert_b \neq \vert v \vert_b\}$. There is a hint in the task that one should first construct the context free grammar for cases such as 
$L_1 = \{u\#v \mid u,v \in \{a,b\}^* , \vert u \vert_a > \vert v \vert_a\}$ and later combine all of these.

I would appreciate a hint to come up with $L_1$. I do not know how construct $u\#v$ such that $u$ and $v$ are free independent from each other except of the fact that $u$ has more $a$'s than $v$. I tried to build my language around the $\#$ and also tried to move the $\#$ in the direction of the most appearing $a$'s but none of my attempts worked.

What is the proper way to tackle such constructions in general?

Comment: @greybeard Thank you. I don't think it is nessecary to keep this discussion here, so I deleted the other comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just show how to build a grammar for  $L_1 = \{ u\#v, |u|_a > |v|_a \}$. Then it'll be straightforward to combine 4 similar grammars into a grammar for $L$.

The idea is to write $u\#v$ as $xay\#v$ with $x,y,v \in \{a,b\}^*$ and $|y|_a = |v|_a$.  The construction of $y\#v$ is handled by the non-terminal $Z$ which "grows" it from the center.

$$
\begin{align*}
S &\to aS \mid bS \mid aZ \\
Z &\to bZ \mid Zb \mid aZa | \,\#
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will be able to solve the other grammars with your solution of this example. I am new to this topic and have a hard time to think into this construction tasks.

Comment: You're welcome. Often times a language can be thought as the union or concatenation or simpler languages.

Comment: Why? The part preceding $aZ$ can have any number of $a$s and $b$s.

Comment: @greybeard Consider $S \Rightarrow bS \Rightarrow baS \Rightarrow baaS \Rightarrow baaaZ \Rightarrow baaaZb \Rightarrow baaa\#b$. Obviously $baaa$ does have $3$ $a$'s more than $b$.

Comment: Correct - I missed that you have productions with the start symbol on the right side.